# Access tinymce from thickbox

Tags: tinymce, thickbox, iframe

Basically, I have a custom tinymce button which opens a thickbox window in iframe mode.
Is there a way to access the tinymce from the iframe? Wordpress media uploader seems to do it somehow.

Stuff like `$('#content', window.parent.document).tinymce().getContent()` does not work.

PS. If that's impossible, I'll have to do use the tinymce default popup window, but Good God it's ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tinyMCE isn't implemented as a jQuery plugin. I'm not sure, but this would be more probable:

```
window.parent.tinyMCE.get('editor').getContent()
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I forgot to replace **editor** with **content**

Comment: @VladChernushevich : in the Stack, one say "thanks" upvoting ;)

Comment: @brasofilo Gladly, but _Vote Up requires 15 reputation_ :)

Comment: @VladChernushevic : oh, apologies, didn't know/remember but won't forget that... you're closer now ;)